# Why isn't my file load not working in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xampp

I can't see why this code isn't working. The output from load_docs_2.php is:
**Array ( ) Incorrect file type**.  This is being run on XAMPP.

The HTML is:

```
<form id="import_form" method="post" action="load_docs_2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for "importfile">Import PDF File</label><br>
  <input id="import_name" name="load" type="file" value="Upload File"><br><br>
  <input id="import" name="import" type="submit" value="Import">
</form>
```

load_docs_2.php is:

```
<?php

// Capture file data

print_r($_FILES);

$loadname = $_FILES["load"]["name"];  // name contains original name
$loadname_temp = $_FILES["load"]["tmp_name"];  // tmp_name contains the temporary file name

// Check file meta data
$import_size = $_FILES["load"]["size"];
$import_type = $_FILES["load"]["type"];

// Setting target folder
$target_dir = "./Staff Docs";
$target_file = $target_dir . $loadname;  // Create target file path

// Move to import folder

$allowed =  array('pdf');
$ext = pathinfo($loadname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (!in_array($ext,$allowed))
{
    echo 'Incorrect file type';
}    
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($loadname_temp, $target_file);
}

?>
```

Why isn't the file load working?

Comment: Can you please end with a final question, i had to backtrace all the way to the title there, i dont really agree to start a question with the title, but dont repeat it in the actual question. IMO its best to put a final recap after the code.

Comment: $target_dir = "./Staff Docs/";   target folder is Staff Docs means you have to end with forward slash

Comment: is there any error showing ?

Comment: target folder and source code folder both in same directory ? or different ?

Comment: Fix the title. It is `is not not working` now.

Answer (score 0):

you can change this code

```
$target_dir = "Staff Docs/";
```

now its working fine

Comment: Staff Docs is in the same directory as the source code file.

Comment: The issue is that the print_r($_FILES) statement in load_docs_2.php is outputting the result:  Array ( ).  ie the files data is not being passed to load_docs_2.php

Answer (score 0):

Your Target File is not correct. There is no Directory Separator between the Target Directory and the File so the result would be essentially wrong.

```
 <?php

    // Capture file data

    print_r($_FILES);

    $loadname       = $_FILES["load"]["name"];  // name contains original name
    $loadname_temp  = $_FILES["load"]["tmp_name"];  // tmp_name contains the temporary file name

    // Check file meta data
    $import_size    = $_FILES["load"]["size"];
    $import_type    = $_FILES["load"]["type"];

    // Setting target folder
    //$target_dir   = "./Staff Docs";   //<== THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM WAS...
    $target_dir     = "./Staff Docs/";  //<== ADD A DIRECTORY SEPARARATOR BEFORE CONCATENATING WITH $loadname...
    $target_file    = $target_dir . $loadname;  // Create target file path

    // Move to import folder
    $allowed        =  array('pdf');
    $ext = pathinfo($loadname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (!in_array($ext,$allowed)){
        echo 'Incorrect file type';
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($loadname_temp, $target_file);
    }
```

Optionally, you can add the Directory Separator directly on the line that describes the $target_file like so:

```
 <?php

    // Capture file data

    print_r($_FILES);

    $loadname       = $_FILES["load"]["name"];  // name contains original name
    $loadname_temp  = $_FILES["load"]["tmp_name"];  // tmp_name contains the temporary file name

    // Check file meta data
    $import_size    = $_FILES["load"]["size"];
    $import_type    = $_FILES["load"]["type"];

    // Setting target folder
    $target_dir     = "./Staff Docs";   //<== THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM WAS...
    $target_file    = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $loadname;  // Create target file path

    // Move to import folder
    $allowed        =  array('pdf');
    $ext = pathinfo($loadname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (!in_array($ext,$allowed)){
        echo 'Incorrect file type';
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($loadname_temp, $target_file);
    }
```